# Not able to create maven project under eclipse mars even after setting the proxy

Tags: spring

[image]

Hi Everyone , 
I am new to Maven environment . Tried all possibilities of enabling the proxy under settings.xml .But no use. Since the maven is integrated in mars I couldn't find the settings.xml and created my own under .m2 . And also tried with the external maven also .But no results .

Below is my settings.xml .

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>hostname</host>
      <port>port</port>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The failed request from before has been cached by Maven. You need to run the command with the `-U` flag to retry. (Or wait until the caching has expired...)

Comment: Since the maven is integrated in eclipse mars I could create the maven project without the archetype but if I select with the archetype the above error resulted . And I'm confused where to run this -u command since it is integrated. Can you please explain it in a broader way nfechner.